# Moda en un array

Tags: java

Trato de ver que está mal en el código pero todavía no he podido encontrar respuesta,ayuda por favor

```
public int moda(int[] a){
  int moda=0;
  int Rep=0;

  for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++) {
    int cantRep=0;
   for(int j=0;j<a.length-1;i++) {

     if(a[i]==a[j])

     cantRep++;

     if(cantRep>Rep) moda=a[i];
     Rep=cantRep;

   }
  }

  return moda;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow, te sugiero que te pases por [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para que tengas una guía de como preguntar, falta muchas más información en tu pregunta ya que ni siquiera indicas que error te esta dando ni en que momento da el error. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No logro entender bien tu código pero lo poco que alcanzo a entender es que en tu condición

```
 if(a[i]==a[j])
```

Solo estas iterando una vez, osea tienes solo un for

```
 for(int i = 0; i < limite; i++{
   if(a[i]==a[j])
  }
```

Lo que se alcanza a entender es que estas comparando un dato de tu arreglo "a[]" en el indice i con  otro dato en tu mismo arreglo "a[]" en el indice j, aquí el error es que jamas entra en el indice j, hay que agregar otro for, de esta forma:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < limite; i++{
  for(int j = 0; j < limite; j++{
   if(a[i]==a[j]){
      //condición
     }
    }
  }
```

Si pudieras explicar mejor tu pregunta y tu código podría darte una mejor solución a tu problema